# Problem with Classic ASP Breakpoints in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: debugging, iis, visual-studio-2005, iis-7, asp-classic

I am trying to set a breakpoint in an ASP page that isn't working correctly.

I am doing this in visual studio 2005 on Windows server 2008.

Whenever I try to set the breakpoint with the mouse, the IDE opens up a different page and sets a breakpoint somewhere in that page. I don't know why it is doing this.

I have better luck setting the breakpoint using F9, but those breakpoints don't get hit, anyway. The breakpoints that are set in the page that visual studio opens automatically are getting hit, but this doesn't help me, because I don't need to debug that page!

This is my first time debugging classic ASP, so I could use some help.

Thanks

Comment: I'm really looking forward to an answer to this question : I gave up on classic asp breakpoints a while ago, it was such a hassle to set up, and wouldn't work properly anyways ... but maybe there is a way to get it to work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested debugging of classic ASP in VS 2008 on server 2008 and it works fine.  I haven't got VS2005 to test it on that.

However if memory serves I've seen this problem when the root folder for the web site project (and you are using a web site not a web application project right?) and the Home directory path in the IIS configuration.  E.g., the VS solution points to an UNC path whereas the IIS points to a physical drive.  In this case VS can't marry up the file path of the script in the ASP process with the file path of source code in the solution.

Comment: It is a web site, not an app. When I load the site in VS, I am selecting a site in IIS on that server, So I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
In VS.NET: 
project - properties
  configuration properties
     debugging
        - enable ASP debugging
        - enable ASP.NET debugging

In the IIS snap-in: 
  default Website - properties
      home directory tab
         configuration
            app debugging
               - enable ASP server-side script debugging
   Website (the project you want to debug) - properties
      directory tab
         application name: add

Add IIS process account to Debugger Users group: 
   In Computer Management snap-in:
      System Tools
         Local Users and Groups
            Groups
               Debugger Users - properties
                  Add user IWAM_machine-name (the "Launch IIS process account")

Now, to debug in VS.NET: 
   right-click the .asp page that the application should start from
      select "Set as Start Page"
```

Comment: That looks like instructions for IIS6.